# keras.models.load_model("") gives error on h5f.open()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When using `keras.models.load` it throws an error on `h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)` and says `OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`.

DNNModel file code

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.regularizers import l1, l2
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def set_seeds(seed = 100):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    
def cw(df):
    c0, c1 = np.bincount(df["dir"])
    w0 = (1/c0) * (len(df)) / 2
    w1 = (1/c1) * (len(df)) / 2
    return {0:w0, 1:w1}

optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.0001)

def create_model(hl = 2, hu = 100, dropout = False, rate = 0.3, regularize = False,
                 reg = l1(0.0005), optimizer = optimizer, input_dim = None):
    if not regularize:
        reg = None
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(hu, input_dim = input_dim, activity_regularizer = reg ,activation = "relu"))
    if dropout: 
        model.add(Dropout(rate, seed = 100))
    for layer in range(hl):
        model.add(Dense(hu, activation = "relu", activity_regularizer = reg))
        if dropout:
            model.add(Dropout(rate, seed = 100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return model
```

Loading Model and Parameters

```
# Loading the model
import keras
model = keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/Hussein Ali/Desktop/d/DNNModel.py")
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 # Loading the model
      2 import keras
----> 3 model = keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/Hussein Ali/Desktop/d/DNNModel.py")

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py:533, in File.__init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, fs_strategy, fs_persist, fs_threshold, fs_page_size, page_buf_size, min_meta_keep, min_raw_keep, locking, alignment_threshold, alignment_interval, **kwds)
    525     fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0,
    526                      locking, page_buf_size, min_meta_keep, min_raw_keep,
    527                      alignment_threshold=alignment_threshold,
    528                      alignment_interval=alignment_interval,
    529                      **kwds)
    530     fcpl = make_fcpl(track_order=track_order, fs_strategy=fs_strategy,
    531                      fs_persist=fs_persist, fs_threshold=fs_threshold,
    532                      fs_page_size=fs_page_size)
--> 533     fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
    535 if isinstance(libver, tuple):
    536     self._libver = libver

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py:226, in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    224     if swmr and swmr_support:
    225         flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 226     fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    227 elif mode == 'r+':
    228     fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

File h5py\_objects.pyx:54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py\_objects.pyx:55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py\h5f.pyx:106, in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Comment: You already asked this in the Keras mailing list and got an answer, .py files are not model files, you have to save your model as model.save('something.hdf5') to be able to load it with load_model.

Comment: what do you have in `DNNModel.py`? If you have python code then it is wrong file. You may eventually `import DNNModel` to have this code in current file. But `load_model` needs file like `h5` which keeps only `weights` from model - not its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` can means few different elements.

- python code in variable `model`
- model's weights saved in file `H5`

And you are confusing these concepts.

---

If you want to load code from `DNNModel.py` then use standard `import`

```
import DNNModel

model = DNNModel.create_model()
```

but this gives fresh model without pretrained `weights` in model, and it needs long time to train it.

So we use file `H5` to keep pretrained `weights` from model,
and later we load it again to create model with pretrained `weights`,
and we don't have to waste time to train it again.

```
models.save_model('my_model.h5')   # save pretrained model in file
```

```
model = keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')  # load pretrained model from file
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining ,I will  try the way you said

Comment: I have just started learning AI,coming from java
what is the best way and resource for  learning Neural network as your experience ,  a light useful tutorial not a long complicated that is practical
Thanks again

Comment: frankly, I use `Google` to search partial information on internet. But there are specialized portal which have more information; Even [Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/) has some courses, tutorials. They have even video tutorials on YouTube. [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) has also tutorials. [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) has competitions - so you can check yourself. Similar [hackatons on AnalyticsVidhya](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/)

Comment: [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) should have also tutorials. You could also see [Andrew Ng](https://www.andrewng.org/) and his courses on [DeepLearning.AI](https://www.deeplearning.ai/)